# Ruby Rails - Query is Fast, Until I Print Output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This takes 5 seconds

```
games = Game.where(league: 1).where.not(date: d).joins(:scores).select(:home_score)
puts games[-1].home_score
```

This takes 1 second

```
games = Game.where(league: 1).where.not(date: d).joins(:scores).select(:home_score)
```

Why does the first section of code take so long? Does the query not run until I try to print out the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is right.

`games` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, the database will be queried only when you really need the data.

`games[-1]` will trigger the data loading.